# Two screen overlapping flutter?

Tags: flutter, user-interface

I am new to flutter development  and i am doing it from past 3 months and i never have that issue when i press back.

Whenever i press back and back to home screen screen overlap:

[image: Problem Screenshot]

here is my code of home screen:

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
 State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
 }

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
   BannerAd _bottomBannerAd;
   bool _isBottomBannerAdLoaded = false;

  final BannerAd myBanner = BannerAd(
   adUnitId: 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111',
   size: AdSize.banner,
   request: AdRequest(),
   listener: BannerAdListener(),
  );

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    myBanner.load();
   }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Container(
 
     child: Scaffold(
        bottomNavigationBar: Container(
          height: 50,
          width: 320,
          child: AdWidget(ad: myBanner,),
        ) ,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[NavBar(), Body()],
          )),
       ));
   }
   }

  class Body extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return ResponsiveLayout(
  largeScreen: LargeChild(),
  smallScreen: SmallChild(),
     );
  }
 }

  class LargeChild extends StatelessWidget {
   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
    height: 600,
        child: Stack(
    fit: StackFit.expand,
    children: <Widget>[
     
      FractionallySizedBox(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          widthFactor: .6,
          child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 48),
              child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      "Memory Game",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 60,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontFamily: "Montserrat-Regular",
                          color: Color(0xFF111111)),
                    ),
                    RichText(
                      text: TextSpan(
                        text: "Say Hi to ",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 60, color: Color(0xFF8591B0)),
                        children: [
                          TextSpan(
                              text: "",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 60,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                // color: Colors.black54
                              ))
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),

                    SizedBox(
                      height: 40,
                    ),
                    Search()
                  ])))
        ],
       ),
      );
     }
    }

     class SmallChild extends StatelessWidget {
     @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(40),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            "Memory Game!",
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 60,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontFamily: "Montserrat-Regular",
                color: Colors.white),
          ),
          RichText(
            text: TextSpan(
              text: "Play Now",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 60, color: Color(0xFF8591B0)),
              children: [
                TextSpan(
                    text: "",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 40,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                     
                    ))
              ],
            ),
          ),
          
          SizedBox(
            height: 32,
          ),
          Search(),
          SizedBox(
            height: 30,
          )
        ],
      ),
    ));
    }
   }
```

Problem:Whenever i press back whole screen apears in back of home screen as you can see in the provided gif.
Can someone please tell me that why is this happening?

Comment: There are few things is not clear here; like `ResponsiveLayout`

Comment: You did not placed Scaffold in the SmallChild and LargeChild class, wrap singleChildscrollView with Scaffold.

Answer (score 0):

Its happening just because you have written `backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,` in your `Scaffold`

Try to change it with some another color and check it out, you will not face the problem.